# Why does my barbajs transitions stop working when bundled with parcel?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parcel, barbajs

So I have this basic website template I used from a video on Barba.js to diagnose wether this issue was due to parcel or barba. When I ran the code without bundling with parcel, the transitions worked fine aswell as the links. However when I bundled with parcel and ran npm run dev, my href links stopped working and so did the transitions, while the console showed 0 errors. Here are the 4 files of code.

about.html

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title>Page Transition Using BarbaJS & GSAP</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
            </head>

            <body data-barba="wrapper">
            <div class="load-container">
                <div class="loading-screen"></div>
            </div>

            <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="about-section">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1 class="title animate-this">
                        about page
                    </h1>
                    <div class="animate-this button">
                        <a href="index.html">go back to home</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            </body>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
            <script
                    type="text/javascript"
                    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js"
            ></script>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
            </html>
```

index.html

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title>Page Transition Using BarbaJS & GSAP</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
            </head>

            <body data-barba="wrapper">
            <div class="load-container">
                <div class="loading-screen"></div>
            </div>

            <main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home-section">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1 class="title animate-this">
                        home page
                    </h1>
                    <div class="animate-this button">
                        <a href="about.html">go to about</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            </body>

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/@barba/core"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
            </html>
```

main.css

```
            html,
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background: #161616;
                color: white;
            }

            .loading-screen {
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 0;
                padding-right: 0;
                padding-top: 0;
                background-color: #4bedc2;
                width: 0%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .load-container {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                overflow: hidden;
                z-index: 10;
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            h1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 38%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                font-family: "Cosi Azure";
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .button {
                position: absolute;
                top: 60%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }

            .button a {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                border: 1px solid white;
                padding: 24px 40px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                letter-spacing: 4px;
                font-size: 10px;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .button:hover a {
                background: white;
                color: #161616;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }
```

main.js

```
            function delay(n) {
                n = n || 2000;
                return new Promise((done) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        done();
                    }, n);
                });
            }

            function pageTransition() {
                var tl = gsap.timeline();
                tl.to(".loading-screen", {
                    duration: 1.2,
                    width: "100%",
                    left: "0%",
                    ease: "Expo.easeInOut",
                });

                tl.to(".loading-screen", {
                    duration: 1,
                    width: "100%",
                    left: "100%",
                    ease: "Expo.easeInOut",
                    delay: 0.3,
                });
                tl.set(".loading-screen", {left: "-100%"});
            }

            function contentAnimation() {
                var tl = gsap.timeline();
                tl.from(".animate-this", {duration: 1, y: 30, opacity: 0, stagger: 0.4, delay: 0.2});
            }


            barba.init({
                sync: true,

                transitions: [
                    {
                        async leave(data) {
                            const done = this.async();

                            pageTransition();
                            await delay(1000);
                            done();
                        },

                        async enter(data) {
                            contentAnimation();
                        },

                        async once(data) {
                            contentAnimation();
                        },
                    },
                ],
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the async attributes in front of the hooks made it work.